How to separate "use server" and "use client" in NextJs 14
I am currently learning NextJs 14 and would like to use server components as much as possible.
Unfortunately, I have to use "use client" to use the Maplibre map. At least I have not found any other way. Here is my code, which works so far.
"use client"

import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Map, NavigationControl, GeolocateControl } from "maplibre-gl";
import 'maplibre-gl/dist/maplibre-gl.css';
import { Suspense } from "react";
import { Spinner } from "@/components/spinner";


const CdayMap = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const map = new Map({
      container: 'map',
      center: [7, 50],
      zoom: 14,
      style: 'https://tiles.versatiles.org/assets/styles/colorful.json'
    });
    map.addControl(new NavigationControl());

    map.addControl(
      new GeolocateControl({
        positionOptions: {
          enableHighAccuracy: true,
        },
        trackUserLocation: true,
      })
    );
  }, [])

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
      <div className="flex-1 flex flex-col items-center gap-y-4 animate-fade-from-top">
        <div id="map" />
      </div>
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export { CdayMap };

Next, I want to integrate markers and clusters using this tutorial: https://maplibre.org/maplibre-gl-js/docs/examples/cluster/
Here is my code, which unfortunately only shows a few points. I suspect that is because async and await cannot be used in a client component.
"use client"

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import maplibregl, { Map, NavigationControl, GeolocateControl } from "maplibre-gl";
import 'maplibre-gl/dist/maplibre-gl.css';
import { Suspense } from "react";
import { Spinner } from "@/components/spinner";


const CdayMap = () => {

  const [pageIsMounted, setPageIsMounted] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setPageIsMounted(true)
    const map = new Map({
      container: 'map',
      center: [-103.59179687498357, 40.66995747013945],
      zoom: 3,
      style: 'https://tiles.versatiles.org/assets/styles/colorful.json'
    });
    map.addControl(new NavigationControl());

    map.addControl(
      new GeolocateControl({
        positionOptions: {
          enableHighAccuracy: true,
        },
        trackUserLocation: true,
      })
    );

    map.on('load', () => {
      map.addSource('earthquakes', {
          type: 'geojson',
          data: 'https://maplibre.org/maplibre-gl-js/docs/assets/earthquakes.geojson',
          cluster: true,
          clusterMaxZoom: 14, 
          clusterRadius: 50 
      });

      map.addLayer({
          id: 'clusters',
          type: 'circle',
          source: 'earthquakes',
          filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
          paint: {
              'circle-color': [
                  'step',
                  ['get', 'point_count'],
                  '#51bbd6',
                  100,
                  '#f1f075',
                  750,
                  '#f28cb1'
              ],
              'circle-radius': [
                  'step',
                  ['get', 'point_count'],
                  20,
                  100,
                  30,
                  750,
                  40
              ]
          }
      });

      map.addLayer({
          id: 'cluster-count',
          type: 'symbol',
          source: 'earthquakes',
          filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
          layout: {
              'text-field': '{point_count_abbreviated}',
              'text-size': 12
          }
      });

      map.addLayer({
          id: 'unclustered-point',
          type: 'circle',
          source: 'earthquakes',
          filter: ['!', ['has', 'point_count']],
          paint: {
              'circle-color': '#11b4da',
              'circle-radius': 4,
              'circle-stroke-width': 1,
              'circle-stroke-color': '#fff'
          }
      });

      // inspect a cluster on click
      map.on('click', 'clusters', (e) => {
          const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
              layers: ['clusters']
          });
          const clusterId = features[0].properties.cluster_id;
          const zoom = map.getSource('earthquakes').getClusterExpansionZoom(clusterId);
          map.easeTo({
              center: features[0].geometry.coordinates,
              zoom
          });
      });

      map.on('click', 'unclustered-point', (e) => {
          const coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
          const mag = e.features[0].properties.mag;
          let tsunami;

          if (e.features[0].properties.tsunami === 1) {
              tsunami = 'yes';
          } else {
              tsunami = 'no';
          }

          while (Math.abs(e.lngLat.lng - coordinates[0]) > 180) {
              coordinates[0] += e.lngLat.lng > coordinates[0] ? 360 : -360;
          }

          new maplibregl.Popup()
              .setLngLat(coordinates)
              .setHTML(
                  `magnitude: ${mag}<br>Was there a tsunami?: ${tsunami}`
              )
              .addTo(map);
      });

      map.on('mouseenter', 'clusters', () => {
          map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
      });
      map.on('mouseleave', 'clusters', () => {
          map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
      });
  });


  }, [])

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
      <div className="flex-1 flex flex-col items-center gap-y-4 animate-fade-from-top">
        <div id="map" />
      </div>
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export { CdayMap };

Is my assumption correct? How can I achieve my goal?

since a client component is rendered on the client, you cannot create server action in a client component.

Create a new file and add the user server direct at the top of the file
and now the any function and create inside the file will be the consider a server action

